# Cannot open PKPass after updating certificate

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

Since I updated my certificate, no pkpass can be open from any ios device, i've tried on MAC, on different ios phone and I can't open the pkpass or put it in the wallet

Im pretty sure the problem is with the certificate since it's the only thing that changed but I can't understand why it doesnt work this time. It's not the first time we update it (since the certificate expire every year)

I've use this website (https://pkpassvalidator.com/) that I found to validate my pkpass and everything seem fine.

I tried to debug it with XCode (i'm not sure if I did it right) but in the log, I had "Trust evaluate failure: [leaf KeySize MissingIntermediate SSLHostname TemporalValidity]". (don't know if it help or not and I only got it 1 time, I tried again with another pkpass and I didnt have that log)

I know there is a "intermediate" certificate and I checked on the production machine and I see it on the server (WWDR Certificate (Expiring 02/07/2023 21:48:47 UTC)).

I'm not sure what to do next, I can provide a test pkpass by email if needed (or I can try to make it accessible by my website but I will be harder)

Comment: Did you use the same CSR or use the same private key to generate the CSR?  If not then your key may not match your new certificate.

Comment: I did request a new CSR from my mac (opening the KeyChain > Ask a certificate from a certificate authority (my MAC is in french, so maybe I translate it wrong)) and added the same email / name and then used that CSR on https://developer.apple.com/account/ to created the certificate

Not sure how to "use the same private key"? All the certificate were generated from the same MAC?

Comment: The step I use are as follow: Generate a new CSR, upload it on my apple acount, download the new certificate, install it on the MAC, export it in .p12 format with a password, then install it on the production machine and use it to sign the pass. Those step haven't change so it almost certain it the certificate who is invalid, but I dont understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Have you exported both the certificate and it's the private key?  What errors do you see in the console log when you try to open the pass on an Apple device?

Comment: I'm pretty I tried to export the certificate while having the certificate selected or while having the key selected (if that how you expert the private key (didnt see a check mark "export private key" or something like that)). I tried to look for error on the device with XCode, I had many "log" not really "error" or I wasnt at the right place cause I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: I can also upload a test pkpass on my google drive (or anywhere else, not sure where) or send it to you by email if that help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly after debugging some more, I saw that there was a thumb.db file added to the pkpass.

There was a problem with the manifest.json and that file, which caused the pkpass to stop opening, so I just changed the way we make the pkpass to not add that file.

Thanks to @PassKit I was able to see the error on the console of my MAC and correct it.